# mongodb get count without repeating find

Tags: mongodb, count

When performing a query in MongoDb, I need to obtain a total count of all matches, along with the documents themselves as a limited/paged subset.

I can achieve the goal with two queries, but I do not see how to do this with one query.  I am hoping there is a mongo feature that is, in some sense, equivalent to SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, as it seems like overkill to have to run the query twice.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

EDIT:  Here is Java code to do the above.

```
     DBCursor cursor = collection.find(searchQuery).limit(10);
     System.out.println("total objects = " + cursor.count());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which language you're using, but you can typically call a `count` method on the cursor that's the result of a `find` query and then use that same cursor to obtain the documents themselves.

Comment: thanks for your help, it works like a charm.  I am using Java and the cursor has a count method.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. The question asks how to do it with one *query*. Using `cursor.count()` actually just delegates the second query to the client driver, but the second query is still executed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only overkill to run the query twice, but there is also the risk of inconsistency. The collection might change between the two queries, or each query might be routed to a different peer in a replica set, which may have different versions of the collection.

The count() function on cursors (in the MongoDB JavaScript shell) really runs another query, You can see that by typing "cursor.count" (without parentheses), so it is not better than running two queries.

In the C++ driver, cursors don't even have a "count" function. There is "itcount", but it only loops over the cursor and fetches all results, which is not what you want (for performance reasons). The Java driver also has "itcount", and there the documentation says that it should be used for testing only.

It seems there is no way to do a "find some and get total count" consistently and efficiently.