# Performing mongodb query for both count and extract the result in an efficient way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm performing a query on a collection containing more than 3000 documents with support for pagination.

What it does is first count the number of documents in the result then perform another query to extract the result and pass the result for rendering.

I mean it's doing the same thing twice which i think it will make the searching more slow.

```
    // first query for counting the number of documents in the result
    collection.find({$or:[{name: {$regex: pattern, $options: 'i'}}, {author: {$regex: pattern, $options: 'i'}}]}).count(function(er, count) {

        // second query to get all the documents in the result
        collection.find({$or:[{name: {$regex: pattern, $options: 'i'}}, {author: {$regex: pattern, $options: 'i'}}]}).skip(pagination.claculate_skip_offset_index(param_val)).limit(pagination.items_per_page).toArray(function (err, docs) {

            options = pagination.options(param_val, query, collection_name, count);
            res.render('pages/search', {
                title: 'Search - '+query,
                songs: docs,
                options: options,
            });
        });
    });
```

It makes the browser hang for a little bit when i perform different searches. And I feel like it's not an efficient way. Is there anyway to improve this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `db.foo.find(querydoc)[.skip(pagesize*pagenum)].limit(pagesize)`.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, I think OP is asking how to know number of pages in advance. that's why getting count first place. Better approach is not to get count and just keep fetching next page with your approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890529/mongodb-get-count-without-repeating-find

Comment: @Saleem I'm counting the number of documents so that i can calculate the number of pages and the last page for navigation.

Comment: @devasem db.yourColl.count() and db.yourColl.find().count() do this trick...

Comment: Well, if you have to count it once. Do some kind of caching. It's more like having snapshot count. It may not be accurate but will definetely performant

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg what 's the difference between the two? Could you please explain?

Comment: @devasem The former is a built in, while the latter actually creates a cursor on the server and return its size.